# <select>にMaterialDesignLiteのmdl-menu classを指定するとselectが消えてしまう。

Tags: angularjs, material-design

以下のようにangularJSのサンプルプログラムに、MDLをマウントして書きました。

include.html:

```
<DOCUTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Angular JS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-message-format.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/include.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
</head>
 <body ng-controller="MyController as my">
 <form class="mdl-layout__content">
 <label class="mdl-typography--font-regular" for="temp">テンプレート：</label>
<select class="mdl-menu" id="temp" name="temp" ng-model="my.template" ng-options="t.url as t.title for t in my.templates">
<option  value="">
 以下から選択してください。
</option>
</select>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col" ng-include="my.template" onload="my.onload()"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

include.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function() {
  this.templates = [
       //テンプレート情報（オプションラベルと読み込み先URL）
       { title: 'execution', url: 'templates/execution.html' },
       { title: 'tempo', url: 'templates/tempo.html' }
      ];
      //テンプレートを読み込んだ際に実行されるコード
      this.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.template);
      };
});
```

tempo.html:

```
<dl>
 <dt>アッチェレランド</dt>
 <dd>だんだんはやく</dd>
 <dt>リタルダンド</dt>
 <dd>だんだんおそく</dd>
 <dt>ピュウ モッソ</dt>
 <dd>今までよりもはやく</dd>
 <dt>テンポ ルバート</dt>
 <dd>はやさを柔軟に伸縮させて</dd>
</dl>
```

execution.html:

```
 <dl>
  <dt>マルカート</dt>
  <dd>ひとつひとつの音をはっきりと演奏する</dd>
  <dt>ストリンジェンド</dt>
  <dd>だんだんせきこんで</dd>
  <dt>レガート</dt>
  <dd>音の間を切れ目なくなめらかに演奏する</dd>
  <dt>トレモロ</dt>
  <dd>急速に反復して演奏する</dd>
 </dl>
```

include.htmlのように、selectにclass="mdl-menu"等と書いてしまうと、表示が消えてしまいます。そのため、MaterialDesignで指定されているような動きを持ったSELECTBOXを作れなくて困っています。デモでは

demo.html

```
        <a class="android-link android-link-menu mdl-typography--font-light" id="developers-dropdown">
          For Developers
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-menu--top-left mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="developers-dropdown">
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">App developer resources</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Android Open Source Project</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Android SDK</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Android for Work</li>
        </ul>
```

と記載しており、動いております。（動き的にはこれは左下から右上に動きますが、実際にはプルダウンさせたいので、左上から右下や上から下にrippleさせたいなと思っています）

MaterialDesignではMenuの項目で以下のリンクのような説明をしており、何かしら方法があると思っています。

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus

MaterialDesignLiteのMenuでは以下のリンクのように説明しています。

http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section

Answer (score 1):

angular-material というプロジェクトがありました。

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.autocomplete/directive/mdAutocomplete